# Use Extruct to get node value items in json-id format

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

Code below does not error. However it is not returning the desired elements. When I loop through the data item list the items are there but I don't understand why my loop for SportsEvent to get awayTeam and homeTeam, Stadium, and startdate are coming up blank. The links here dont have second pages so you can remove selenium and get_next_page function and calls if your dont have these installed to test.

The problem lies in this line

```
if "SportsEvent" in item:
```

Here entire script

```
import pandas as pd
import extruct as ex
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

urls = [
    'https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/odds',
    'https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/odds'
]

def get_driver():
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    return driver

def get_source(driver, url):
    driver.get(url)
    return driver.page_source

def get_json(source):
    return ex.extract(source, syntaxes=['json-ld'])

def get_next_page(driver, source):
    """IN the event teams are on more than 1 page Parse the page source and
    return the URL for the next page of results.

    :param driver: Selenium webdriver
    :param source: Page source code from Selenium

    :return
        URL of next paginated page
    """

    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//link[@rel="next"]')
    if elements:
        return driver.find_element_by_xpath('//link[@rel="next"]').get_attribute('href')
    else:
        return ''


df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['awayTeam', 'homeTeam','location','startDate'])

def save_teams(data, df):
    """Scrape the teams from a schema.org JSON-LD tag and save the contents in
    the df Pandas dataframe.

    :param data: JSON-LD source containing schema.org SportsEvent markup
    :param df: Name of Pandas dataframe to which to append SportsEvent

    :return
        df with teams appended
    """

    for item in data['json-ld']:
        print(item)
        if "SportsEvent" in item: #issue is here it does not see SportsEvent in item so it wont continue doing the inner loops
            for SportsEvent in item['SportsEvent']:
                #print(item['SportsEvent'])

                row = {
                    'awayTeam': SportsEvent.get('awayTeam', {}).get('name'),
                    'homeTeam': SportsEvent.get('homeTeam', {}).get('name'),
                    'location': SportsEvent.get('location', {}).get('name'),
                    'startDate': SportsEvent.get('startDate')
                    
                    
                }
                print(row)
                df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)

    return df


for url in urls:
    
    print(url)

    # Save the teams from the first page
    driver = get_driver()
    source = get_source(driver, url)
    json = get_json(source)
    df = save_teams(json, df)

    # Get teams on each paginated page if other pages exists
    next_page = get_next_page(driver, source)
    paginated_urls = []
    paginated_urls.append(next_page)

    if paginated_urls:

        for url in paginated_urls:

            if url:

                #print(next_page)
                driver = get_driver()
                source = get_source(driver, url)
                json = get_json(source)
                df = save_teams(json, df)
                next_page = get_next_page(driver, source)
                paginated_urls.append(next_page)
```

Comment: Are you just trying to get the away team, home team, date and location?

Comment: yes, chitown88 that is correct. I elected to use extruct because the other sports on this site Basketball and Baseball use the same layout so code would be useful to extract in those other sports as well.

Comment: Look at my solutions below (specifically the last part EXTRA:). That's probably a better way to do this,

Comment: Thank you great response. The Selenium works. It is there in the event that there are more pages it will get the next page and also return data. In this example your right not needed left it because I didn't want to modify code and break something. Question what app did you use to display the key,type,value. That looks very useful.

Comment: Well, theoretically, the data should all be there (even if it is on multiple pages). IS there an example of the data on multiple pages?

Comment: thats the IDE Spyder

Comment: Ah I see I use VSCode. Would be nice to have that feature to see data better. You asked about an example with multiple pages. I cant find one here on odds shark currently but. If you like extruct and want to see it work on multiple pages this is a great article. Check it out. https://practicaldatascience.co.uk/data-science/how-to-scrape-json-ld-competitor-reviews-using-extruct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239465/discussion-between-leo-torres-and-chitown88).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there is no key `"SportsEvent"` in your `item`. Its a value under the key `'@type'`.

[image]

So you'd need to alter your `save_teams()` function to:

```
def save_teams(data, df):
    """Scrape the teams from a schema.org JSON-LD tag and save the contents in
    the df Pandas dataframe.

    :param data: JSON-LD source containing schema.org SportsEvent markup
    :param df: Name of Pandas dataframe to which to append SportsEvent

    :return
        df with teams appended
    """

    for item in data['json-ld']:
        print(item)
        if "SportsEvent" in item.values(): #issue is here it does not see SportsEvent in item so it wont continue doing the inner loops
                row = {
                    'awayTeam': item.get('awayTeam', {}).get('name'),
                    'homeTeam': item.get('homeTeam', {}).get('name'),
                    'location': item.get('location', {}).get('name'),
                    'startDate': item.get('startDate')
                    
                    
                }
                print(row)
                df = df.append(row, ignore_index=True)

    return df
```

But it looks like you may be complicating this with Selenium. You can get that data by simply pulling it out with BeautifulSoup, then read it into json. Then let pandas flatten it out:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = [
    'https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/odds',
    'https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/odds']

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'html.parser')
    jsonStr = soup.find('script', {'type':'application/ld+json'}).text
    
    jsonData = json.loads(jsonStr)
    df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData)
    
    print(df.to_string())

    # or to get just those columns
    #print(df[['awayTeam.name','homeTeam.name','location.name','startDate']])
```

**Output:**

```
@type           @context inLanguage                                          name                                                                                  url                  startDate location.@type               location.name location.address.@type location.address.addressLocality awayTeam.@type         awayTeam.name homeTeam.@type             homeTeam.name
0   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US       Tampa Bay Buccaneers vs New York Giants       https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/new-york-tampa-bay-odds-november-22-2021-1411211  2021-11-22T20:15:00-05:00          Place       Raymond James Stadium          PostalAddress            Raymond James Stadium     SportsTeam       New York Giants     SportsTeam      Tampa Bay Buccaneers
1   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US                Detroit Lions vs Chicago Bears          https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/chicago-detroit-odds-november-25-2021-1411216  2021-11-25T12:30:00-05:00          Place                  Ford Field          PostalAddress                       Ford Field     SportsTeam         Chicago Bears     SportsTeam             Detroit Lions
2   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US           Dallas Cowboys vs Las Vegas Raiders         https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/las-vegas-dallas-odds-november-25-2021-1411221  2021-11-25T16:30:00-05:00          Place            AT&amp;T Stadium          PostalAddress                 AT&amp;T Stadium     SportsTeam     Las Vegas Raiders     SportsTeam            Dallas Cowboys
3   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US           New Orleans Saints vs Buffalo Bills      https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/buffalo-new-orleans-odds-november-25-2021-1411226  2021-11-25T20:20:00-05:00          Place           Caesars Superdome          PostalAddress                Caesars Superdome     SportsTeam         Buffalo Bills     SportsTeam        New Orleans Saints
4   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US               Houston Texans vs New York Jets         https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/new-york-houston-odds-november-28-2021-1411231  2021-11-28T13:00:00-05:00          Place                 NRG Stadium          PostalAddress                      NRG Stadium     SportsTeam         New York Jets     SportsTeam            Houston Texans
5   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US    Indianapolis Colts vs Tampa Bay Buccaneers   https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/tampa-bay-indianapolis-odds-november-28-2021-1411236  2021-11-28T13:00:00-05:00          Place           Lucas Oil Stadium          PostalAddress                Lucas Oil Stadium     SportsTeam  Tampa Bay Buccaneers     SportsTeam        Indianapolis Colts
6   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US        New York Giants vs Philadelphia Eagles    https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/philadelphia-new-york-odds-november-28-2021-1411241  2021-11-28T13:00:00-05:00          Place             MetLife Stadium          PostalAddress                  MetLife Stadium     SportsTeam   Philadelphia Eagles     SportsTeam           New York Giants
7   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US           Miami Dolphins vs Carolina Panthers           https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/carolina-miami-odds-november-28-2021-1411246  2021-11-28T13:00:00-05:00          Place           Hard Rock Stadium          PostalAddress                Hard Rock Stadium     SportsTeam     Carolina Panthers     SportsTeam            Miami Dolphins
8   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US      New England Patriots vs Tennessee Titans    https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/tennessee-new-england-odds-november-28-2021-1411251  2021-11-28T13:00:00-05:00          Place            Gillette Stadium          PostalAddress                 Gillette Stadium     SportsTeam      Tennessee Titans     SportsTeam      New England Patriots
9   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US     Cincinnati Bengals vs Pittsburgh Steelers    https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/pittsburgh-cincinnati-odds-november-28-2021-1411256  2021-11-28T13:00:00-05:00          Place          Paul Brown Stadium          PostalAddress               Paul Brown Stadium     SportsTeam   Pittsburgh Steelers     SportsTeam        Cincinnati Bengals
10  SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US       Jacksonville Jaguars vs Atlanta Falcons     https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/atlanta-jacksonville-odds-november-28-2021-1411261  2021-11-28T13:00:00-05:00          Place             TIAA Bank Field          PostalAddress                  TIAA Bank Field     SportsTeam       Atlanta Falcons     SportsTeam      Jacksonville Jaguars
11  SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US        Denver Broncos vs Los Angeles Chargers       https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/los-angeles-denver-odds-november-28-2021-1411266  2021-11-28T16:05:00-05:00          Place  Empower Field at Mile High          PostalAddress       Empower Field at Mile High     SportsTeam  Los Angeles Chargers     SportsTeam            Denver Broncos
12  SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US      San Francisco 49ers vs Minnesota Vikings  https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/minnesota-san-francisco-odds-november-28-2021-1411271  2021-11-28T16:25:00-05:00          Place              Levi's Stadium          PostalAddress                   Levi's Stadium     SportsTeam     Minnesota Vikings     SportsTeam       San Francisco 49ers
13  SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US         Green Bay Packers vs Los Angeles Rams    https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/los-angeles-green-bay-odds-november-28-2021-1411276  2021-11-28T16:25:00-05:00          Place               Lambeau Field          PostalAddress                    Lambeau Field     SportsTeam      Los Angeles Rams     SportsTeam         Green Bay Packers
14  SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US          Baltimore Ravens vs Cleveland Browns      https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/cleveland-baltimore-odds-november-28-2021-1411281  2021-11-28T20:20:00-05:00          Place        M&amp;T Bank Stadium          PostalAddress             M&amp;T Bank Stadium     SportsTeam      Cleveland Browns     SportsTeam          Baltimore Ravens
15  SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US  Washington Football Team vs Seattle Seahawks       https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/seattle-washington-odds-november-29-2021-1411286  2021-11-29T20:15:00-05:00          Place                 FedEx Field          PostalAddress                      FedEx Field     SportsTeam      Seattle Seahawks     SportsTeam  Washington Football Team


             
@type           @context inLanguage                                            name                                                                                  url                  startDate location.@type                    location.name location.address.@type location.address.addressLocality awayTeam.@type           awayTeam.name homeTeam.@type           homeTeam.name
0   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US         Washington Wizards vs Charlotte Hornets     https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/charlotte-washington-odds-november-22-2021-1460581  2021-11-22T19:00:00-05:00          Place                Capital One Arena          PostalAddress                Capital One Arena     SportsTeam       Charlotte Hornets     SportsTeam      Washington Wizards
1   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US            Cleveland Cavaliers vs Brooklyn Nets       https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/brooklyn-cleveland-odds-november-22-2021-1460586  2021-11-22T19:00:00-05:00          Place       Rocket Mortgage FieldHouse          PostalAddress       Rocket Mortgage FieldHouse     SportsTeam           Brooklyn Nets     SportsTeam     Cleveland Cavaliers
2   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US               Boston Celtics vs Houston Rockets           https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/houston-boston-odds-november-22-2021-1460591  2021-11-22T19:30:00-05:00          Place                        TD Garden          PostalAddress                        TD Garden     SportsTeam         Houston Rockets     SportsTeam          Boston Celtics
3   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US          Atlanta Hawks vs Oklahoma City Thunder    https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/oklahoma-city-atlanta-odds-november-22-2021-1460596  2021-11-22T19:30:00-05:00          Place                 State Farm Arena          PostalAddress                 State Farm Arena     SportsTeam   Oklahoma City Thunder     SportsTeam           Atlanta Hawks
4   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US                 Chicago Bulls vs Indiana Pacers          https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/indiana-chicago-odds-november-22-2021-1460601  2021-11-22T20:00:00-05:00          Place                    United Center          PostalAddress                    United Center     SportsTeam          Indiana Pacers     SportsTeam           Chicago Bulls
5   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US                Milwaukee Bucks vs Orlando Magic        https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/orlando-milwaukee-odds-november-22-2021-1460606  2021-11-22T20:00:00-05:00          Place                     Fiserv Forum          PostalAddress                     Fiserv Forum     SportsTeam           Orlando Magic     SportsTeam         Milwaukee Bucks
6   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US  New Orleans Pelicans vs Minnesota Timberwolves    https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/minnesota-new-orleans-odds-november-22-2021-1460611  2021-11-22T20:00:00-05:00          Place             Smoothie King Center          PostalAddress             Smoothie King Center     SportsTeam  Minnesota Timberwolves     SportsTeam    New Orleans Pelicans
7   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US               San Antonio Spurs vs Phoenix Suns      https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/phoenix-san-antonio-odds-november-22-2021-1460616  2021-11-22T20:30:00-05:00          Place                  AT&amp;T Center          PostalAddress                  AT&amp;T Center     SportsTeam            Phoenix Suns     SportsTeam       San Antonio Spurs
8   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US                  Utah Jazz vs Memphis Grizzlies             https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/memphis-utah-odds-november-22-2021-1460621  2021-11-22T21:00:00-05:00          Place                     Vivint Arena          PostalAddress                     Vivint Arena     SportsTeam       Memphis Grizzlies     SportsTeam               Utah Jazz
9   SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US          Sacramento Kings vs Philadelphia 76ers  https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/philadelphia-sacramento-odds-november-22-2021-1460626  2021-11-22T22:00:00-05:00          Place                  Golden 1 Center          PostalAddress                  Golden 1 Center     SportsTeam      Philadelphia 76ers     SportsTeam        Sacramento Kings
10  SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US                   Detroit Pistons vs Miami Heat            https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/miami-detroit-odds-november-23-2021-1460631  2021-11-23T19:00:00-05:00          Place             Little Caesars Arena          PostalAddress             Little Caesars Arena     SportsTeam              Miami Heat     SportsTeam         Detroit Pistons
11  SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US           New York Knicks vs Los Angeles Lakers     https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/los-angeles-new-york-odds-november-23-2021-1460636  2021-11-23T19:30:00-05:00          Place            Madison Square Garden          PostalAddress            Madison Square Garden     SportsTeam      Los Angeles Lakers     SportsTeam         New York Knicks
12  SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US        Portland Trail Blazers vs Denver Nuggets          https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/denver-portland-odds-november-23-2021-1460641  2021-11-23T22:00:00-05:00          Place  Moda Center at the Rose Quarter          PostalAddress  Moda Center at the Rose Quarter     SportsTeam          Denver Nuggets     SportsTeam  Portland Trail Blazers
13  SportsEvent  http://schema.org      en-US        Los Angeles Clippers vs Dallas Mavericks       https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/dallas-los-angeles-odds-november-23-2021-1460646  2021-11-23T22:30:00-05:00          Place                   Staples Center          PostalAddress                   Staples Center     SportsTeam        Dallas Mavericks     SportsTeam    Los Angeles Clippers
```

**EXTRA:**

I've never used extruct before. I like it! Thanks for intorducing it to me. Here's a solution with that:

```
import pandas as pd
import extruct as ex
import requests

urls = [
    'https://www.oddsshark.com/nfl/odds',
    'https://www.oddsshark.com/nba/odds']

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url).text
    jsonData = ex.extract(response, syntaxes=['json-ld'])['json-ld']
    df = pd.json_normalize(jsonData)
    df = df[df['@type'] == 'SportsEvent']
    
    print(df.to_string())

    # or to get just those columns
    #print(df[['awayTeam.name','homeTeam.name','location.name','startDate']])
```